# Firebase Authentication sends invalid pages

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

Building a Flutter app, I use Firebase Authentication to register users.
When I use

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail()
```

or

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
```

The user receives the email that leads him to a page that says "The selected page mode is invalid." as shown in the screenshot.

[image: The selected page mode is invalid]

Comment: provide some code please